# Traverse Path with Criteria Root element of unkown object structure

Tags: java, persistence, criteria-api

I have a search API that can abstractly search for properties of referenced entities defined in a persistence scheme.
For example i have something like these entities:

```
@Entity
public class EntityA {
@Column
private String someProperty;

@Column
private EntityB someReference;
}

@Entity
public class EntityB {
@Column
private String someProperty;

@Column
private Set<EntityC> someReferences;
}

@Entity
public class EntityC {
@Column
private String someProperty;
}
```

With these entities i can traverse paths (for example when my root is EntityA and im sure that the user searches for a string field within:

```
private Expression<String> getExpression(Root<T> root, String fieldName) {
        String[] propertySplit = fieldName.split("\\.");
        Path<String> path = null;
        for (String property : propertySplit) {
            if (path == null) {
                path = root.get(property);
                continue;
            }
            path = path.get(property);
        }
        return path;
    }
```

Assuming that  is currently EntityA i can call the getExpression method like this:

```
[...]
criteriaBuilder.equal(getExpression(entityARoot, "someProperty"), "myValue");
[...]
```

And i also can invoke references:

```
[...]
criteriaBuilder.equal(getExpression(entityARoot, "someReference.someProperty"), "myValue");
[...]
```

But when the path encounters a Collection Type, then this doesn't work, but i want to do something like this:

```
[...]
criteriaBuilder.equal(getExpression(entityARoot, "someReference.someReferences.someProperty"), "myValue");
[...]
```

Im getting the following exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Illegal attempt to dereference path source [null.someReferences] of basic type
```

I know that there must be a way to archive that since Spring Data can do that with Method-Names in Repositories too.
My goal is to create a function that can traverse any unknown object as long as the final attribute i am checking is the type i know of. So i know every time whether the criteria should compare String, Integer, Boolean, Date etc.

Comment: Have you tried to do a `root.join(property)` or `path.join(property)` in the cases in which the exception is thrown? See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53820207/illegalstateexception-using-criteriabuilder-for-getting-a-list-in-java.

Comment: Unfortunatelly Path<> does not have the function join .. Root does, but i think i would need path to have it as well. But it doesnt..

Comment: Maybe you can cast the object returned by `get(property)` to an interface that contains that `join()` method and call it. I think the best way to check this is by debugging and watching for the real class of the returned object by `get(property)`. The `join()` method is declared in the `From<>` interface, and `Root<>` inherits from it: https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/criteria/From.html.

Comment: what about joining every time root.property is an @Entity itself? given the java type of Root: `Class rootClass = ((RootImpl) root).getEntityType().getJavaType();` with reflection you can find out information about the field root.property and act accordingly: if root.property is a leaf you just create your predicate; while if you are in the case root.property1.property2.property3 and you find out property1 is an @Entity you join the entity and apply the same mechanism on the rest of the path joinProperty1.property2.property3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I stumbled upon an implementation that I think is what you are looking for. Check out code for this project [github.com/perplexhub/rsql-jpa-specification/ ... /RSQLJPAPredicateConverter.java#L49-L130](https://github.com/perplexhub/rsql-jpa-specification/blob/4d6ce586aedeae999b063cb3ef87e7bb9929b168/rsql-jpa/src/main/java/io/github/perplexhub/rsql/RSQLJPAPredicateConverter.java#L49-L130).

I bookmarked this project as something I can import into my existing project, to enable generic handling as you have described in your question. My current implementation is hard coded against all known input predicates.

Comment: This looks very promising! Thank you really much for this! I will try it out at a later point, since im not in the office today. I award you anyways since you brought up a path for me to resolve this issue.

Comment: I checked it and decided to use the rsql implementation. Thank you really much!

Answer (score 0):

Collections of nested entities need to be fetched eagerly if you want immediate access, ie within your query.

```
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER) 
    @Column
    private Set<EntityC> someReferences;
```

Note "someReference.someProperty" and so on is not null safe you will get unexpected results if "someReference" is null. Figuring out how to use Join like the comments above is recommended to avoid this.

Comment: Spring does this too with the naming scheme. When you type something like.. findBySomeReferencesSomeReferenceName(String name); it creates the query somehow even if the properties are lazy